# The Product element is shown as one-third(1/3)

Tags: css, wordpress

I use a plug-in called WPBakery Page Builder. I Set the element layout to 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 in the product page, and add the product to each 1/3 elment, which is set to 1/9 size.

When I analyzed the css, it seems to be a problem caused by the product loading the layout of 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 of the shop page.

When setting up on the main page, the css of the plug-in itself is loaded, but the product page seems to load the css of the theme.

When setting the layout to 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 of the plug-in's layout css can be loaded using the wpbakery plug-in on the product page?

The url in question is https://mo-on.co.kr/shop/obicuum-ps/

[image]

Best, 
Jeil

```css
/*--theme css--*/
.shop-layout-masonry-3.woocommerce .products .product,
.product-layout-masonry-3 .product-promo-wrapper .products .product,
.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce .cross-sells .products .product {
 width: 33.333%;
}

/*--wp bakery plug-in css--*/
.vc_col-sm-4 {
width: 33.33333333%;
}
```

Comment: theme css no need to define width again. And check reset CSS  it might be a floating issue.

Comment: Visual Composer i.e your WP Bakery plugin will not work in WooCommerce page, so you example url is not working with the page builder css.

Comment: We have developed a Plugin that works for Single Product with Visual Composer page builder sample URL : http://studio.0effortthemes.com/